# Hearthstone: It's possible to search NEW cards in the card collection?

Tags: hearthstone

If you enter the text "**legendary**" in the card searcher of the card collection panel, all the legendary cards will be shown. The same happens if you write "**beast**", etc.

Knowing that, my question is:

Can I enter a special search term to find all the new cards that have been added in the card collection?, I mean the cards with the text "**New**" at the bottom of the card, those cards that are recently acquired.

Comment: Hm. This reminds me that i was looking for a way to find the golden cards.

Comment: Do you mean new cards you got from packs or new cards in the game like the next adventure?

Comment: @Martin H. Both are the same, both kind of cards are marked with a "NEW" sign at the bottom of the card

Comment: What he means is if you want to search cards you recently acquired or that were recently released. And @kl78 you can just search for 'golden' or check the 'show golden' radio button

Comment: @Crowley Astray: is this a newer Feature? I remember a half year ago  searching for golden did not work

Comment: @kl78 relatively new, yes. It was introduced this March.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just search for **new** like you would search for **legendary** and get your desired result. All the available search features are explained in this [blog post](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/20056284/search-your-hearthstone-collection-like-never-before-3-17-2016) (thanks to @CrowleyAstray for finding this).

For spanish game language, the proper term is "**nuevas**", as explained **[here](http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/es/blog/20056284/search-your-hearthstone-collection-like-never-before-3-17-2016)**.

Comment: Obviously that was the first thing that I tried... searching for the term "new" doesn't show new cards, doesn't show ANY card.

Comment: @ElektroStudios this only works if you haven't moused over your new cards yet.

Comment: @Riley I'm aware that the text "New" dissapears when you hover mouse on the card. Just what the answer says doesn't works.

Comment: It does indeed work. [Source](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/20056284/search-your-hearthstone-collection-like-never-before-3-17-2016), the official Hearthstone Website on the new search function, it uses 'new' as an example.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray Thanks for finding that post! I edited it into my answer :)

Comment: The problem was that for non-english game language the equivalent traduction didn't worked, I was aware that in my language I must use the equivalent traduction for the search term, however, the spanish traduction they did for the word "New" is in plural (which is wrong, it must be "Nuevo" or "Nueva"), so the real solution is that blog post, thanks a lot you all guys.